# How to plot two cumulative incidence functions on the same graph?

Tags: charts, survival-analysis, survival

I'm performing a survival analysis. I want to plot two cumulative incidence functions on the same graph, one based on age groups (Edad60 variable) and the other on all the patients. I don't know how to combine them.

Here's the code in R:

```
#install.packages("ggsurvfit")
library(ggsurvfit)
#install.packages("tidycmprsk")
library(tidycmprsk)

AML_RC$Cuminc <- factor(AML_RC$Cuminc,
                         levels = c(0,1,2),
                         labels = c("Censor", "Relapse", "Non-Relapse Mortality"))

# By age groups:
cuminc(Surv(SLEmonths, Cuminc) ~ Edad60, data = AML_RC) %>% 
  ggcuminc(outcome = c( "Relapse", "Non-Relapse Mortality")) +
  labs(x = "Months after diagnosis") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, max(AML_RC$SLEmonths), by = 20)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
  theme_classic() +theme(legend.position = 'bottom', legend.direction = "horizontal") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("1" = "salmon2", "2" = "deepskyblue3"),
                     labels = c("1" = "18-60 y.o.", "2" = "61-70 y.o."))

# All patients:
cuminc(Surv(SLEmonths, Cuminc) ~ 1, data = AML_RC) %>% 
  ggcuminc(outcome = c( "Relapse", "Non-Relapse Mortality")) +
  labs(x = "Months after diagnosis") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, max(AML_RC$SLEmonths), by = 20)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
  theme_classic() +theme(legend.position = 'bottom', legend.direction = "horizontal"))
```

Does anyone know how to do this? In the case of survival curves, there's the function ggsurvplot_combine. I imagine there must be something similar for cumulative incidences.

Thank you and happy Women's Day!:)